# Why do you always have to use rendering function, namely renderItem inside flatlist properties in order to retrieve data? What does key extractor do?

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist, mobile-application

I am 3 days into react native doing the mobile app. I try to understand how to dynamically visualize the data, lets say from just an array, of a game object with an id and name. I want to showcase games in a list style, so i can scroll through games. As i understand it is a must to create a constant in which the rendered item from a list is going to be put, gameItem for ex.

I want to showcase games in a list style, so i can scroll through games. As i understand it is a must to create a constant in which the rendered item from a list is going to be put, gameItem for ex.

Comment: You are not forced to use FlatList, it's just convenient to. If you want you can iterate over your array with `.map` and render item by returning  a react component

Answer (score 0):

The `renderItem` function is a required prop for the FlatList component, and it is responsible for rendering each individual item in the list. This function is called for each item in the data array, and it returns a React component that represents the item.

The `keyExtractor` prop is another prop for the FlatList component, and it is responsible for providing a unique key for each item in the list. The keyExtractor function is called for each item in the data array, and it returns a string that uniquely identifies the item.

Hence, the `renderItem` function is responsible for rendering each individual item in the list, while the `keyExtractor` function is responsible for providing a unique key for each item in the list.
These functions are necessary for efficient rendering and recycling of off-screen items.